# Ignore {% extends %} when included (Django templates)

Tags: django, django-templates, include, extends

I have a template which I want to be accessable from `include` and also to be accessable as a standalone page with `extends`.

There is a `Base.html`:

```
    <!-- some html, navbar -->
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    <!-- footer and other stuff -->
```

There is a `HomePage.html`:

```
    {% extends 'Base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    <!-- some HomePage content -->
    {% endblock %}
```

There is a `MyTemplate.html`:

```
    {% extends 'Base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    <!-- some content from MyTemplate -->
    {% endblock %}
```

What I want is to add `MyTemplate.html`'s content to HomePage. If I will add `{% include 'MyTemplate.html' %}` to `HomePage.html` then I will get two navbars because `Base.html` is extended two times. But I still need `MyTemplate.html` be accessable as a standalone page with navbar and other `Base.html` stuff.
How to ignore `{% extends %}` if the template is included from another one?

At the moment as a workaround I added another file, say `MyPage.html`. This file extends `Base.html` and includes `MyTemplate.html`. `HomePage.html` also includes `MyTemplate.html` and `MyTemplate.html` doesn't extend anything. I just wanted to know if there is more appropriate way to do what I want.

**UPD**: I use two views. One of them uses `HomePage.html` and another one uses `MyTemplate.html` (`MyPage.html` at the moment).

Comment: I don't understand... did you use `MyTemplate.html` for your view?

Comment: @seuling There is a view that uses `MyTemplate.html` and another view that uses `HomePage.html`.

Answer (score 0):

`extends` can use a yesno template filter. You can use something like this in HomePage.html

```
{% extends request.some_flag|yesno:"Base.html,none.html" %}
```

set `some_flag = True` or `False` on basis of your condition (none.html could be a empty file). That way you can specify when you went to extend Base.html or not. You can also specify a variable

```
{% extends my_file %}
```

where `my_file = "Base.html"` or `"none.html"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess I still need to create unnecessarry file `none.html`. With that I would rather choose my option. @shivam-singh

Answer (score 0):

I create a directory called `includes` in this I created `MyTemplate.html` file.

This is my `HomePage.html`

```
{% extends 'Base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% include 'includes/MyTemplate.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is my `MyTemplate.html`

```
<div>
<!-- some content from MyTemplate -->
</div>
```

It is working fine for me. I am not included `{% extends 'Base.html' %}` in `MyTemlate.html` because it is already retrieved in `HomePage.html`

Comment: May be I wasn't clear. Sometimes I want to use `MyTemplate.html` directly from the view and that's why I need to extend `Base.html` in it.

Comment: @ArtyomIlyin That's the point of this answer, you shouldn't use the same template for such different use cases. If you do what this answer suggests you can use `HomePage.html` from views, and include `MyTemplate.html` in other templates when needed.

Comment: @BrianH. I see the point of this answer. It just doesn't fit my purposes. I have a workaround but I thought there was a better way.